# Creating a custom control in asp.net that has javascript properties and methods

Tags: jquery, asp.net, custom-controls

As a starting point for creating custom controls, I would like to make a control that simply displays a number. If we imagine the .ascx file contains nothing except for a literal control, and the code behind sets that value to 1.

I then want to be able to do myControl.increment();
This will run some javascript that increases the value of the literal control.

I could inject a javascript into the page, such as pseudocode:

```
page_load
{

  scriptything.register("function increment(x) { $('#myLiteral').increment(); });

}
```

or something, but that wouldn't be myControl.increment, that would just be increment(). More than one control on the page would screw it up.

Anyone know how I can achieve my goal of coupling the javascript with the custom control? Am I asking the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to look at JavaScript class development like this as one example (there are others): http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/objects

You may really want to look at developing ASP.NET AJAX controls, which integrate server-side controls and AJAX capabilities.  I developed a few and I have written a few articles on this subject:

- http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/reuse-recycle-extend.aspx
- http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/Building-a-Custom-AJAX-Control-with-the-Help-of-jQuery.aspx

  - http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/ajax-abstraction.aspx

For JQuery, use this:

- Plugins: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring
- Widgets: http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the links, unfortunately I can't use the AJAX control toolkit. With regards to objects in Javascript, I understand how they work, but I don't know how to associate them with my custom control. Do you have any ideas on that? I want to be able to do `$('#myCustomControlID').increment();` if possible.

Comment: The syntax you provided is a JQuery plugin or widget, edited response above.

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible.

I have a class CalledCustomControlLibrary.

it contains several folders which include images and scripts.  You can include those types of items using `[assemply: WebResource]`

IE

```
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlLibrary.LeftRight.local_img.leftArrow.jpg", "img/jpg")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlLibrary.LeftRight.local_img.rightArrow.jpg", "img/jpg")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlLibrary.LeftRight.local_js.leftright.js", "application/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlLibrary.global_js.jquery-1.3.2.js", "application/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlLibrary.global_js.mousehold.js", "application/javascript")]
```

Then in the onload event of the class you can register the client scripts like:

```
        string tsJQueryJS = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "CustomControlLibrary.global_js.jquery-1.3.2.js") ;
        string tsMousehold = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "CustomControlLibrary.global_js.mousehold.js");
        string tsLeftRightJS = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "CustomControlLibrary.LeftRight.local_js.leftright.js");

        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("JQuery" )) { Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("JQuery", tsJQueryJS); }
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("Mousehold")) { Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("Mousehold", tsMousehold); }
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("LefRightJS")) { Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("LeftRightJS", tsLeftRightJS); }
```

The entire control is housed simply in the class. which inherits WebControl and IPOstBackDataHandler.  This control in particular is for a control that has a left and right arrow button and increments or decrements the number value in the text box based on holding the buttons.